# IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, intellisense

I get the following error :

`argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"`

Here is my code :

```
static char *getFmuPath(const char *fileName) {
    char pathName[MAX_PATH];
    int n = GetFullPathName(fileName, MAX_PATH, pathName, NULL);
    return n ? strdup(pathName) : NULL;
}
```

I have declared `MAX_PATH` but it still shows error in pathname

```
#define MAX_PATH 4096
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You basically have two options. 1. Avoid `TCHAR*`, `LPTSTR`, `LPCTSTR` and friends, or any APIs that reference them in any form. If you see any such API, use its ...W or ...A counterpart explicitly (`GetFullPathNameA` in this case). 2. Avoid `char*` and `wchar_t*`, use  `TCHAR*`. When you need to interface `TCHAR*` with `char*` and `wchar_t*`, use explicit conversions. Option 2 is less recommended.

Comment: i have done changing from **char** to **TCHAR**  now the the error is gone but now in **strdup(pathname)** it is showing same error

Comment: Your program would benefit from choosing between C or C++. Mixing the two tends to produce a program that's suffers from the worst of the two languages, and gets few of the benefits of either.

Comment: "now in strdup(pathname)" That's because `strdup` is a `char*` function. That is, you have not finished replacing `char` yet. The `TCHAR*` counterpart would be `_tcsdup`. BTW have you missed the remark that Option 2 is less recommended? Let me say it again so you won't miss it: **Option 2 is less recommended**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't take a `char *`. Look at the docs, it takes `LPTSTR` and `LPCTSTR`.

Depending on your build settings, `LPTSTR` and related types will become either `char*` (ANSI builds) or `wchar_t*` (Unicode builds). You are building as Unicode.

Also, I don't know why you are defining `MAX_PATH`. That is a Windows constant so you should not re-define it.

Comment: what is the changes needed..? in this case. can you tell me.

Comment: Change your types to those required by the function. You're using types that `GetFullPathName` doesn't work on. That's even what the error message says.

Comment: for **MAX_PATH** is flagged its ok but still couldn't figure it how to resolve

Comment: @PrajwalBhat Your function is simply taking the wrong argument type, if you're compiling as Unicode, you should be using `wchar_t*`. If you want ASCII, change it in your project settings.

Comment: int n = GetFullPathName(fileName, MAX_PATH, _T(pathName), NULL);              will this work

Comment: @szczurcio .where exactly in project settings can u guide

Comment: @PrajwalBhat Google `msvc set character set`

Comment: @PrajwalBhat There are people here carefully reading your question and comments, and giving you advice. Please show respect by doing the same for them.

Comment: @tenfour i am new to stack overflow but definitely i shall do it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tenfour,
if you would still like to enforce your system work with ANSI chars so char* would work, change your code to call directly `GetFullPathNameA`
Or, better yet, use unicode character set under Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Character Set.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (VS2017). Changed the project to compile 32-bit and it compiled great! My problem was that I deleted all the extra files in the directory to clean it up and it defaulted to 64-bit because I was building on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: You should write the program so that it works with 32-bit and 64-bit.